# VB.NET Adding an image so that it shows up under My.Resources.TheImageName

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, resources, embedded-resource

Using VS2012, I would like to add an image to the My.Resources. namespace.
I would like to draw this image to a PictureBox on the Paint event.

I did the following:

I clicked "Add existing item", then I opened up the image.
I clicked the image from the Solution Explorer and set the Build Task to "Embedded Resource".

I saved the project and re-built it.
But it still does not show up under My.Resources.

What did I do wrong, please?

Thank you for the help!

ps:

I do not want to add it directly to "Resources.resx" (for example by clicking the "BackGroundImage" property of a form). 
I would prefer having the image in the solution explorer instead. I once experienced that VS2012 once damaged a file, and I had to rebuild the resource file. I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the image to the Resources tab in Project Properties, not to the project directly.

Comment: `My.Resources` comes from ResX files.  If you don't want to use ResX, you can't use `My.Resources`.